# How to generate "on click" link from any given day - equal or greater than today (and, let say, in a month span - in JavaScript, HTML & CSS calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I'm a beginner programmer - a student actually - and this is my very first calendar I recreated using HTML, CSS & JavaScript.

I want to use this calendar as a part of a booking system, so I'm wondering about the next step for me to make each individual day in the calendar an active link, that - being clicked - takes a user to an individual web page where to follow with the booking for that particular day.

The HTML code goes like this:

```
<h3 class="header">Elija la fecha y la sesión del evento</h3>

<div class="container">
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class="calendar__info">
            <div class="calendar__prev" id="prev-month">&#9664;</div>
            <div class="calendar__month" id="month"></div>
            <div class="calendar__year" id="year"></div>
            <div class="calendar__next" id="next-month">&#9654;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="calendar__week">
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">lun</div>
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">mar</div>
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">mié</div>
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">jue</div>
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">vie</div>
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">sáb</div>
            <div class="calendar__day calendar__item">dom</div>
        </div>
        <div class="calendar__dates" id="dates"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/static/script.js"></script>
```

The CSS code:

```
html {
  font-size: 50%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: coral;
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.calendar {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #222227;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 3rem rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.calendar__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #008080;
}

.calendar__prev, .calendar__next {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calendar__prev {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.calendar__next {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.calendar__month, .calendar__year {
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

.calendar__week, .calendar__dates {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.calendar__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5rem;
  line-height: 4;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.calendar__item:hover {
  background-color: #262626;
  border: 0.2rem solid #777;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The JavaScript code:

```
let monthNames = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

let currentDate = new Date();
let currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
let monthNumber = currentDate.getMonth();
let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

let dates = document.getElementById('dates');
let month = document.getElementById('month');
let year = document.getElementById('year');

let prevMonthDOM = document.getElementById('prev-month');
let nextMonthDOM = document.getElementById('next-month');

month.textContent = monthNames[monthNumber];
year.textContent = currentYear.toString();

prevMonthDOM.addEventListener('click', ()=>lastMonth());
nextMonthDOM.addEventListener('click', ()=>nextMonth());

writeMonth(monthNumber);

function writeMonth(month) {
    for (let i = startDay(); i > 0; i--) {
        dates.innerHTML += `<div class="calendar__item">${''}</div>`;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= getTotalDays(month); i++) {
        dates.innerHTML += `<div class="calendar__item">${i}</div>`;
    }
}

function getTotalDays(month) {
    if (month === -1) month = 11;

    if (month == 0 || month == 2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 7 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        return 31;
    } else if (month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 10) {
        return 30;
    } else {
        return isLeap() ? 29 : 28;
    }
}

function isLeap() {
    return ((currentYear % 100 !==0) && (currentYear % 4 === 0) || (currentYear % 400 === 0));
}

function startDay() {
    let start = new Date(currentYear, monthNumber, 1);
    return ((start.getDay() - 1) === -1) ? 6 : start.getDay() - 1;
}

function lastMonth() {
    if (monthNumber !== 0) {
        monthNumber--;
    } else {
        monthNumber = 11;
        currentYear--;
    }

    setNewDate();

}

function nextMonth() {
    if (monthNumber !== 11) {
        monthNumber++;
    } else {
        monthNumber = 0;
        currentYear++;
    }

    setNewDate();
}

function setNewDate() {
    currentDate.setFullYear(currentYear, monthNumber, currentDay);
    month.textContent = monthNames[monthNumber];
    year.textContent = currentYear.toString();
    dates.textContent = '';
    writeMonth(monthNumber);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

as you have not explained the problem you are having and that you are trying to debug your code to randomly find what could go wrong, and that anyway you did not put the css and the html here, j improvised a little

```js
const
  LANG = 'es-Es' // 'en-US'
, datPickPrev = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th:nth-of-type(1)')
, datPickNext = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th:nth-of-type(3)')
, datPick_M_Y = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th:nth-of-type(2)')
, datPickDays = document.querySelector('#date-picker > tbody')
  ;
let now = new Date()
var currDte = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),1 ) 

// init Head Days ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let
  newRow = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead').insertRow()
, wDat   = new Date(currDte.getTime())
    ;
wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() - wDat.getDay()) 

for (let c=0;c<7;++c)
  {
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = wDat.toLocaleDateString(LANG, {weekday:'short'}) // narrow
  wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() +1)
  }

// add day rows  
for (let r=0;r<6;++r)
  datPickDays.appendChild( newRow.cloneNode(true) )
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setGridDays() 

datPickPrev.onclick = _ =>
  {
  datPickPrev.classList.add('clickedMonth')
  setGridDays(-1) 
  setTimeout(_=>{ datPickPrev.classList.remove('clickedMonth') }, 200)
  }
datPickNext.onclick = _ =>
  {
  datPickNext.classList.add('clickedMonth')
  setGridDays(+1) 
  setTimeout(_=>{ datPickNext.classList.remove('clickedMonth')}, 200)
  }
datPickDays.onclick = ({target}) => 
  {
  if (!target.matches('td.clickMonth')) return

  target.classList.add('clickedMonth' )
  if (parseInt(target.textContent) < 20)  datPickNext.click()   
  else                                    datPickPrev.click()  
  setTimeout(_=>{ target.classList.remove('clickedMonth') }, 200)
  }
function setGridDays(movMonth = 0)
  {
  const
    mm = (currDte.getMonth() + movMonth + 12) % 12
  , yy = currDte.getFullYear() - (mm===11 ? 1 : 0) + (!mm ? 1 : 0)
    ;
  currDte = new Date(yy,mm,1)

  let wDat = new Date(currDte.getTime())
  wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() - wDat.getDay()) 

  datPick_M_Y.textContent = currDte.toLocaleDateString(LANG, {month:'long', year:'numeric'}).replace(' de ',' ')

  for (let r=0;r<6;++r)
  for (let c=0;c<7;++c)
    {
    datPickDays.rows[r].cells[c].textContent = wDat.getDate()
    datPickDays.rows[r].cells[c].classList.toggle('clickMonth', (wDat.getMonth()!==mm))
    wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() +1)
    }
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 16px;
  }
td,th {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  text-align : center;
  }
thead { 
  background : #0d3269a9;
  color      : #e4eefc;
  text-align : center;
  }
.clickMonth {
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
tbody td.clickMonth {
  background : #b0c4dea8;
  color      : grey;
  }
.clickMonth:hover {
  color      : #c72734;
  background : #dcd91491; 
  }
.clickedMonth  {
  color      : yellow !important;
  background : crimson !important; 
  }
table#date-picker > thead > tr > th:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }
```

```html
<table id="date-picker">
  <thead>
    <tr> <th class="clickMonth">⇦</th> <th colspan="5"></th> <th class="clickMonth">⇨</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```